# Installing night-light switch on hot-neutral-ground circuit

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, neutral

I am attempting to add a light switch that has a night light in it to my workshop. I noticed that the switch box only has one neutral wire leading to it, and what appears to be a ground wire tied into the box.

The house was built in the 1950s, and the switch requires a neutral wire going from both the switch and the night light for both to work. Is there any easy way to accomplish this?

[image: lightswitch]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That won't work.  The problem with this *and any other powered switch, dimmer, motion sensor, etc.* is that the switch itself is a load.

As such the powered switch needs always-hot and neutral *all by itself*, and of course it also needs a switched-hot wire so it can operate the light.  That is three wires, and the ground doesn't count.

I see where you have only one /2 Romex with two wires in it.  That means it is a "switch loop" (that's a google word) and will not have a neutral.  (Or perhaps it is wired backwards, and it has a neutral and no hot).

Since you have the wall off, consider replacing that /2 run with a /3. That will provide what you require.  Use the red for the switched-hot.

This is now required for new construction.

Another option is to use a "smart switch" to control the light, which talks wirelessly to a control module in the light fixture.  In this case the control is wireless and the switch loop wires are redesignated as always-hot and neutral.

Comment: I assume that to install /3 I'd have to do it all the way back to the breaker panel?

Comment: @nerdenator no, only back to the lamp.  Since your box has only one /2 cable coming in, it must be a switch loop.   Google "switch loop" and all will make sense.  Keep in mind most switch loop illustrations will show *exactly what you have* because they haven't been updated to reflect current NEC requirement of /3 cable. That requirement is to solve this problem.